# Error in forEach when use a consumer to avoid try-catch in forEach in Java8

Tags: java-8

I have a log() method to avoid try catch statement in forEach() below which was working in other code.

```
public <T> Consumer<T> log(LogConsumer<T, Throwable> logConsumer)
{
    return i -> {
        try
        {
            logConsumer.accept(i);
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            log("e = " + e);
        }
    };
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface LogConsumer<T, E extends Throwable> {
    void accept(T t) throws E;
}
```

Now I just want to use log in forEach below but I have the red rippled line in LINE such that

`new Task.runJob(job, type))`

> I have red rippled line under job, type in 
>       "runJob(Job, JobType) in Task cannot be applied to (java.lang.Object, < lambda parameter>)"
>
> Now sure how to fix it to use log in forEach just to avoid
>   try-catch inside of it.

```
execute() {
    Map<Job, JobType> map = getJobMap();

    map.forEach( log((job, type)-> new Taks().runJob(job,type)) );    // LINE: error here 
}

class Task {
    public String runJob(Job job, JobType type) throws Exception
    {
        ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I needed to use BiConsumer instead of Consumer, but thank for the comment anyway Ilya Serebryannikov

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you cannot execute functions that throw exceptions using lambda expressions. You have to handle the exception using `try-catch` block. However, in order for your code to look more readable, create a function, that will handle the exception and return the desired result.

```
class Task {
    public String runJob(Job job, JobType type)
    {
        try {
            ...
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In case if you care what will be the result, map it and filter for the result of your function is not null, otherwise, ignore it, but watch logs for any errors.

And then call it like shown below.
Notice: *both ways work below, but the second way is more robust because you can handle the scenario when not all jobs were executed without exception.*

```
execute() {
    Map<Job, JobType> map = getJobMap();

    // First way
    map.forEach( log((job, type) -> new Taks().runJob(job,type)) );

    // Another way
    List<Object> batchResult = map.entrySet().stream()
            .map((job, type) -> new Task().runJob(jon, type))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if (batchResult.size() == map.size()) {
        // everythings is ok (all operations resulted in non-null result
    } else {
        // Have to study logs and figure out what went wrong
    }

}
```